# Task management software for linux / multi-platform

Tags: linux, cross-platform, task-management

For a long time now, I've been looking for a program to manage my own tasks and projects.

A little while ago, I started programming a program with these features:

- Add tasks
- Add subtasks
- Set priority
- Set a wait syntax to tasks (if I'm waiting for a package for exmaple)
- Set "Do this, before this" syntax and vise versa
- link two tasks together
- Add notes to tasks

Here is a screenshot of that:
[image: screenshot]

I work as an IT support and has seen several people at work needing help installing MS project. I never actually knew how it worked until today, and it is in the same area as of what I'm looking for.

I looked online at some alternative applications, but most of them has too much focus on *teams* and saves the data on *their* servers instead of locally. Most of them was also Web-based (which is OK, but I prefer GUI or cli)

I'm on linux and are wondering if there are any good alternatives, either GUI or cli application.

If anyone could help me, it would speed up my (personal) working a lot!

**EDIT**

I use wine for some applications, and it could be an option

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of task (or to-do list) applications for Linux, but most of them only manage flat lists, without good support for subtasks.  A couple that support subtasks, priorities, categories, and notes, are:

- Task Coach (https://www.taskcoach.org/)
- Task Unifier (http://taskunifier.sourceforge.net/)

These both have GUI interfaces.  If you want a command-line application, probably the most widely used one is the todo.txt format (http://todotxt.org/)--there are also GUI applications that use the same format.  The todo.txt format doesn't support subtasks or predecessors/successors.

Zim Wiki (https://zim-wiki.org/) is a hybrid outliner/wiki that also supports to-do list items with subtasks.  It's features make it suitable for managing projects if your approach focuses on documentation more than on a work breakdown structure.

If you are open to running applications under Wine, there are many more Windows to-do list applications that you could consider.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I use some applications/games with wine, and could be an option